# AngularJS: How should I update a property on a resolved promise inside of my watch listener?

Tags: angularjs, promise

Consider [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fAWYSKeQAdv9GuT56lon?p=preview).

Inside of my watch listener, I'd like to update a property on a resolved promise.

- Is it correct to modify values on the `$$v` property?
- If not, then what should I do?

---

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="ng-app" ng-app="myAngularApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <input ng-model="myDto.Weight" />{{myDto.Status}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var myDto = {Weight: 200, Status: 'Acceptable'};

var myAngularApp = angular.module('myAngularApp', []);

myAngularApp.factory('myService', function($q){
  return {
    getMyDto: function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(myDto);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
});

myAngularApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, myService){
  $scope.myDto = myService.getMyDto();
  $scope.$watch('myDto.Weight', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if (newVal < 150) {
      $scope.myDto.$$v.Status = 'Too Light!'; // Is this the recommended way of doing it?
    }
    else if (500 < newVal) {
      $scope.myDto.$$v.Status = 'Too Heavy!';
    }
    else if (Number(newVal)) {
      $scope.myDto.$$v.Status = 'Acceptable';
    }
    else {
      $scope.myDto.$$v.Status = 'Not a number!';
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The other answers do a good job of addressing this specific question; however, it should be noted that any variable or property in Angular prefixed with `$$` is a private variable and shouldn't be modified or depended upon.

Comment: @BrandonTilley: I suspected as much, but I feel like the AngularJS documentation should call this out specifically somewhere and tell people what to do instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't modify `$$v` directly, it's an implementation detail.  Instead, use `then` to get the result of the promise, then use it however you like.  That requires minimal change to your code.

[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/h2xPxZDFJKZmEl457oqP?p=preview)

```
myAngularApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, myService){
  ($scope.myDto = myService.getMyDto()).then(function(myDto) {
    $scope.$watch('myDto.Weight', function(newVal, oldVal){
      if (newVal < 150) {
        myDto.Status = 'Too Light!'; // Is this the recommended way of doing it?
      }
      else if (500 < newVal) {
        myDto.Status = 'Too Heavy!';
      }
      else if (Number(newVal)) {
        myDto.Status = 'Acceptable';
      }
      else {
        myDto.Status = 'Not a number!';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Buu! This was the piece I needed to get my watch on a promise variable returned from a function to work in my code... Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

It is a little bit weird to modify the promise since a promise represents the result of an action that is performed asynchronously. It is self-contained.

I think it is better to add another service function to update data the status. Try this

```
myAngularApp.factory('myService', function ($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return {
        getMyDto: function () {
            deferred.resolve(myDto);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        updateStatus: function (status) {
            myDto.Status = status;
            deferred.resolve(myDto);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

myAngularApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, myService) {
    $scope.myDto = myService.getMyDto();
    $scope.$watch('myDto.Weight', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal < 150) {
            myService.updateStatus('Too Light!');
        } else if (500 < newVal) {
            myService.updateStatus('Too Heavy!');
        } else if (Number(newVal)) {
            myService.updateStatus('Acceptable');
        } else {
            myService.updateStatus('Not a number!');
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0qUNou4mTV1PnCveeohd?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Interesting. It looks like you're keeping the state in the service, and I've seen other people recommend doing the same.

Comment: @JimG. Technically you can handle the data anywhere. However you should make the service self-contained, and it is more testable and easy to maintain. And you'd better use a function call to update the data, not the way demonstrated in the other answer.

Comment: If the view is changing Weight directly, why is it bad to have the controller update Status? Creating a whole new method in the service just to modify a exposed property, it doesn't feel like JavaScript (or AngularJS) to me.

Comment: in your code  myDto is a promise so where is the difference to OPs code?